# Refresh page on browser when returning from an android app

Tags: javascript, android-intent

I have a platform that goes step by step in a questionnaire. In one step I use an intent to open an android application which is a game. So, the process is that the user answers some questions (on the web) and then plays a game (android app). The platform is built with Django and the android app with Unity.

When the game is finished, the android app is terminated and the user returns to the browser. How can I track this action and refresh the browser so the process automatically goes on?

An example.
Step 1 - Questionnaire (on a mobile browser)
Step 2 - Game (android application)
Step 3 - Questionnaire (back to the mobile browser)

How can step 3 automatically detects that step 2 is finished and refresh the page?

Comment: Did you try to use deep link?

Comment: Deep link If I'm not wrong is an Android mechanism. In my example, I'm using a mobile browser and an android app. The app is called at some point through Javascript intent, the user plays the game and returns to the browser after the app is terminated. The browser should detect this and refresh.
I saw that from an app to an app this is possible but here I have a browser and an app.

Comment: To detect a user returning from your app to your website, you can add a special parameter to your deep link URL. This parameter can be used to identify that the user is returning from your app.

For example, suppose you have an app called "MyApp" and you want to deep link to a specific page within the app. You can create a deep link URL like this:
myapp://page?id=1234&return_to=mywebsite.com
In this example, the return_to parameter is added to the deep link URL.This parameter tells the app to redirect the user back to the specified website after they have finished interacting with the app.

Comment: To detect the user returning from the app, you can add some JavaScript code to your website that listens for the pagehide or visibilitychange events. When one of these events is triggered, you can check the document.visibilityState property to see if the user has returned to the website.

Comment: @TaronQalashyan thank you for your suggestions. Finally, I used the document.visibilityState listener since the visibility changes when the user leaves the browser and enters the android app. The following did the trick.

`document.onvisibilitychange = function() {
    if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
        location.reload();
      }
    }
  };`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used the document.visibilityState listener since the visibility changes when the user leaves the browser and enters the android app. The following did the trick.

```
document.onvisibilitychange = function() {
  if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
      location.reload();
    }
  }
};
```